# Unable to send an embed from within a cog

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have been working on this discord bot and recently I moved some of its code into a cog, however now, the bot is not able to send an embed. My code editor is showing no errors and I can't seem to figure out the error with my code:

```py
@info.command(name = "galax")
    async def galax(self, ctx):
        print("Command called")
        self.embed_v = discord.Embed(title = "Name", description = "Description", color = discord.Color.random())
        print("Embed declared")
        self.embed_v.set_thumbnail(url = "image url here")
        print("Image set")
        self.embed_v.set_footer(text = "For any further queries, please put them in help-chat", icon_url = self.bot.user.avatar)
        print("Footer set")
        self.embed_v.add_field(name = "Server Status:", value = "status", inline = "True")
        print("status set")
        self.embed_v.add_field(name = "Whitelisted Players(In-Game names):", value = "some stuff**If there's any name missing or incorrectly spelt please report it with /report or !report**", inline = "False")
        self.embed_v.add_field(name = "Current Server Version:", value = "version", inline = "True")
        print("Version set")
        self.embed_v.add_field(name = "Server IP:", value = "ip.....", inline = "True")
        print("IP set")
        await ctx.send(embed = self.embed_v)
        print("Embed sent")
```

I have used print statements to see if one peice of code works or not. All of the embed declarations seem to work but it doesn't seem to be able to send the embed. When I replace ctx.send() with normal string, it works.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you replacing "self.embed_v" with just "embed_v"?

Comment: The paramenter `inline` is `bool` type. Pass `True`, not a string `"True"`.

Comment: @ClementGenninasca The code is inside a cog, so the variables need to be self.[variable name], I think.

Comment: @Hazzu I tried that but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: @GreatestQuince8 no since you don't need it to be a cog embed, which just doesn't feel necessary and may cause issues